# I face an error when try to open build view

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-api-31

Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin'.
Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated.

I am New to android programming  and i face this error when try to open build view i serach about it but not found the solution
thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.